# `handle_read_frame error` connecting a Socket.io C++ client to a Socket.io JavaScript server

Tags: javascript, c++, next.js, socket.io

Using Socket.io, I need to make a C++ client connect and exchange real time data to a JavaScript server.

For now I'm running both codes in the same machine, an Ubuntu Linux.

The C++ code, as a class:

**`SocketIO.hpp`**

```
#include "sio_client.h"

class SocketIO 
{
private:
    sio::client io;
    bool connected = false;

public:
    SocketIO();
    ~SocketIO();

    void on_connected();
    void on_closed(sio::client::close_reason const &reason);
    void on_failed();
    void on_message(sio::event &event);

    void init();
};
```

**`SocketIO.cpp`**

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>

#include "SocketIO.hpp"


SocketIO::SocketIO()
{
    std::cout << "Constructor" << std::endl;
}

SocketIO::~SocketIO()
{
    std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl;

    io.sync_close();

    io.socket()->off_all();
    io.socket()->off_error();
}

void SocketIO::on_connected()
{
    std::cout << "on_connected........................................." << std::endl;
    connected = true;
}

void SocketIO::on_closed(sio::client::close_reason const &reason)
{
    std::cout << "on_closed ........................................." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Close event received. Reason = " << reason << std::endl;
    connected = false;
}

void SocketIO::on_failed()
{
    std::cout << "on_failed ........................................." << std::endl;

    io.sync_close();
    connected = false;
}

void SocketIO::on_message(sio::event &event)
{
    std::cout << "on_message ........................................." << std::endl;

    auto data = event.get_message()->get_string();

    std::cout << "MESSAGE RECEIVED:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << data << std::endl;
}

void SocketIO::init()
{
    std::cout << "Initialization" << std::endl;

    io.set_open_listener(std::bind(&SocketIO::on_connected, this));
    io.set_close_listener(std::bind(&SocketIO::on_closed, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    io.set_fail_listener(std::bind(&SocketIO::on_failed, this));
    io.connect("http://localhost:3000");

    // Bind events
    io.socket()->on("download",std::bind( &SocketIO::on_download, this, std::placeholders::_1));

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Loop timer: " << (connected ? "connected" : "disconnected") << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}
```

Calling my class in the main code:

```
int main()
{
    SocketIO io;
    io.init();

    while(true)
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(100));
}
```

Now the JavaScript server part. I'm using NextJs page for the interface, so the server is setup at the server.js inside `/pages/api` path:

```
import { Server } from 'socket.io'

let data = {
    test: "This is a test JSON"
}

const SocketHandler = (req, res) => {

  console.log("Inside socket handler...");

  if (res.socket.server.io) {
    console.log('Socket is already running');
  } else {
    
    console.log('Socket is initializing');

    const io = new Server(res.socket.server, {
      cors: {
        origin: '*',
      }
    });

    res.socket.server.io = io;

    io.on('connection', socket => {
      console.log("Connection in received");

      console.log("Emitting message....")
      console.log(data)
      socket.emit("messsage", data);

      socket.on("disconnect", reason => {
        console.log("Ops! Disconnected");
        console.log("Reason: " + reason);
      })
    })
  }

  res.end();
}

export default SocketHandler
```

When running, the client C++ log:

```
$ ./bin/test
Constructor
Initialization
Loop timer: disconnected
[2023-10-03 09:48:21] [connect] Successful connection
[2023-10-03 09:48:21] [connect] WebSocket Connection 127.0.0.1:3000 v-2 "WebSocket++/0.8.2" /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&t=1696337301 101
on_connected.........................................
[2023-10-03 09:48:21] [error] handle_read_frame error: websocketpp.transport:7 (End of File)
[2023-10-03 09:48:21] [disconnect] Disconnect close local:[1006,End of File] remote:[1006]
Loop timer: connected
Loop timer: connected
Loop timer: connected
Loop timer: connected
Loop timer: connected
[2023-10-03 09:48:26] [connect] Successful connection
[2023-10-03 09:48:26] [connect] WebSocket Connection 127.0.0.1:3000 v-2 "WebSocket++/0.8.2" /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&t=1696337306 101
on_connected.........................................
[2023-10-03 09:48:26] [error] handle_read_frame error: websocketpp.transport:7 (End of File)
[2023-10-03 09:48:26] [disconnect] Disconnect close local:[1006,End of File] remote:[1006]
Loop timer: connected
Loop timer: connected
Loop timer: connected
Loop timer: connected
[2023-10-03 09:48:31] [connect] Successful connection
[2023-10-03 09:48:31] [connect] WebSocket Connection 127.0.0.1:3000 v-2 "WebSocket++/0.8.2" /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&t=1696337311 101
on_connected.........................................
[2023-10-03 09:48:31] [error] handle_read_frame error: websocketpp.transport:7 (End of File)
[2023-10-03 09:48:31] [disconnect] Disconnect close local:[1006,End of File] remote:[1006]
Loop timer: connected
^C
```

The client keeps connecting and disconnecting with the `handle_read_frame` error. The `on_disconnected` event is never called.

The log in the Javascript server:

```
Connection in received
Emitting message....
{
    test: "This is a test JSON"
}
Ops! Disconnected
Reason: transport error
Connection in received
Emitting message....
{
    test: "This is a test JSON"
}
Ops! Disconnected
Reason: transport error
```

That goes in loop forever until the client is stopped.

I've checked the versions. The C++ code is based on https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp - I'm using the master branch according to the compatibility table.

The server code is pretty standard.

I have no clue on what's going behind the scenes, but I understand something is going wrong when establishing a connection.

Interesting is that the connection drops but my disconnection event, at the client side, is not called... Why is it not being called?

What is this `handle_read_frame` transport error is about?